# C# Abstracting methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns, methods, abstraction

I have a set of methods, that take in dates and a bool. These methods then use some SQL then pass it on to another method and return a list. Each method is pretty much the same with the exception of the SQL and the List returned. Now I know there is a better way do these methods but I'm not sure how.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can abstract this or use a better design as the methods are almost identical?

Here is the code:

```
private List<ENT_Message> GetMessageData(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll)
{
    List<ENT_Message> ret = new List<ENT_Message>();
    string sql = "";

    if (IsSelectAll)
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_message";
    }
    else
    {
        sql = " Select * from tbl_message where created_Date between @start_Date and @end_date";
    }

    return Converter.SerializeToMessageList(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql));                   
}

private List<ENT_SensorData> GetSensorData(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll)
{
    List<ENT_SensorData> ret = new List<ENT_SensorData>();
    string sql = "";

    if (IsSelectAll)
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data";
    }
    else
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data where Timestamp between @start_date and @end_Date";
    }

    return Converter.SerializeToSensorDataList(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql)); 
}

private List<ENT_SensorDataEvent> GetSensorDataEvents(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll)
{
    List<ENT_SensorDataEvent> ret = new List<ENT_SensorDataEvent>();
    string sql = "";

    if (IsSelectAll)
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data_event";
    }
    else
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data_event where start_time between @start_date and @end_Date";
    }

    return Converter.SerializeToSensorEventDataList(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql)); 
}

private List<ENT_SensorDataState> GetSensorDataState(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll)
{
    List<ENT_SensorDataState> ret = new List<ENT_SensorDataState>();
    string sql = "";

    if (IsSelectAll)
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data_state";
    }
    else
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data_state where start_time between @start_date and @end_Date";
    }

    return Converter.SerializeToSensorDateStateList(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql)); 
}

private List<ENT_WorkOrder> GetWorkOrders(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll)
{
    List<ENT_WorkOrder> ret = new List<ENT_WorkOrder>();
    string sql = "";

    if (IsSelectAll)
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_workorder";
    }
    else
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data_state where completed_date between @start_date and @end_Date";
    }

    return Converter.SerializeToWorkOrderList(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql));   
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just add the code as part of your question?

Comment: @RQDQ: The code is somewhat long and would make the question less readable. I see no problem with it being somewhere else for clarity.

Comment: @Henk if you look at the code you'll see what list is returned

Comment: @RQDQ: because the code would take alot of space

Comment: This question should be on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @timwi: I've never used that, but I will use this next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could shorten your functions considerably. For example, instead of

```
private List<ENT_SensorDataState> GetSensorDataState(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll)
{
    List<ENT_SensorDataState> ret = new List<ENT_SensorDataState>();
    string sql = "";

    if (IsSelectAll)
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data_state";
    }
    else
    {
        sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data_state where start_time between @start_date and @end_Date";
    }

    return Converter.SerializeToSensorDateStateList(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql));
}
```

you could simply write

```
private List<ENT_SensorDataState> GetSensorDataState(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll)
{
    string sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data_state"
                 + (IsSelectAll ? "" : "where start_time between @start_date and @end_Date");

    return Converter.SerializeToSensorDateStateList(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql));
}
```

That basically reduces your function to the stuff that really matters: The SQL and the name of the serialization function.

Comment: As a result you're still copy/pasting each method. Generics or abstract methods could yield results with less repetition.

Comment: @Abel: True. Still, the SQL is different in each function, so *that part* cannot be generalized.

Comment: hi, this is great but it does not work. It give me an error about "IsSelectAll " not being a string

Comment: @Funky: Sorry, missing parenthesis. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an opportunity to make a generic method. I apologize in advance if I have syntax errors.

```
private List<T> GetData<T>(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll) where T : ENT_Data
{
    List<T> ret = new List<T>();
    string sql = "";

    if (IsSelectAll)
    {
        sql = "select * from " + T.table;
    }
    else
    {
        sql = " Select * from " + T.table + " where created_Date between @start_Date and @end_date";
    }

    return Converter.Serialize<T>(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql));    
}
```

Notice a few things I did:

1. The generic method has a constraint that T is a subclass of ENT_Data, a type I just made up.
2. I gave ENT_Data types a `table` field, for use in your query.
3. The Converter.Serialize methods have also been made generic in a similar manner.

If I missed anything important just let me know.

Comment: You can't constrain T to have a static field/property called `table`.

Comment: You're right, my bad. You would have to make an instance of T and then get the table name.

Comment: Just a thought to make that more generic (write once): Use a parent interface `IEnt_Data` with property `table`. Then have your base concrete class `ENT_Data` have one static method `ENT_Data.Create<T>`, which returns an instance of that type. Then the you can call this with `ENT_Data.Create<T>().table`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<T> GetData<T>(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool IsSelectAll)
        {
            List<T> ret = new List<T>();

            string tableName = "";//Select the table name based on T here
            string sql = "";

            if (IsSelectAll)
            {
                sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data";
            }
            else
            {
                sql = "select * from tbl_sensor_data where Timestamp between @start_date and @end_Date";
            }
            //Build your list using the appropriate converter based on T here        
            return Converter.SerializeToSensorDataList(this.GetData(startDate, endDate, IsSelectAll, sql)); 
        }
```

From that point on, you call

```
GetData<ENT_whatever>()
```

only.

Comment: `tbl_sensor_data` is only relevant for the one method - it really needs to depend on T.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class SqlRetriever, and then subclass each one with the specific SQL message to send.

```
class SqlRetriever {
    public abstract void SendSqlCmd();
    public ArrayList List {
        get; set;
    }
}

class SqlRetrieverXXX
    public const string SqlCmd = " ... ";
    public override void SendSqlCmd()
    {
       /* ... */
    }
}
```

Another possibility, involving less classses, with a worse design is the following one:

```
class SqlRetriever {
        public const string SQLCmd1 = "...";
        public const string SQLCmd2 = "...";

        public void SendSqlCmd(string sqlcmd)
        {
             /*Send the SQL Cmd and store the result in the list */
        }

        public ArrayList List {
            get; set;
        }

        public static ArrayList DoSqlCmd(string sqlCmd)
        {
             var obj = new SqlRetriever();

             obj.SendSqlCmd( sqlCmd );

             return obj.List;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your sql statements and a delegate method in a map where the key is some type T, then make your method generic (method takes type T and returns List of T), you can do a map lookup to get the correct sql statements and delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

You could have one base class all your ENT_* classes inherit from. Then make one method List<ENT_Base>GetData(yourParams). Create a factory method which gets you a list of entities depending on the type of ENT_Base. 
Your GetData() calls that and returns it. 
You will not get around a switch-case or if-then to figure out which kind of entities you have to return.